# Bootstrap font awesome icons not working when in downloaded CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fonts

I am running in a problem here. There are some bootstrap font awesome icons which are not working with the downloaded CSS but working with the same external CDN. Many are working but some are not working like `fa-copyright, fa-credit-card-alt` etc. For example:

Its working with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

But not working when replace with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

even though I copy the content of external CSS and replace with the contents of `font-awesome.min.css` in my `css/` directory. Please help me.

Comment: Rule out caching, and make sure that the browser is loading the latest version of your local CSS file - you will be able to see the contents of this file in the Application panel of the browser dev tool. Alternatively, you could download the latest version of the fontawesome library: http://fontawesome.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It not work, that just the css. You need the font files of font-awesome too, and put them in a folder called fonts. The font files are:

- FontAwesome.otf
- fontawesome-webfont.eot
- fontawesome-webfont.svg
- fontawesome-webfont.ttf
- fontawesome-webfont.woff
- fontawesome-webfont.woff2

And you need the lastest versione too (4.7 i think) or you can't use some of the icons. Just go to their website and download it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You also need to download the fonts themselves as well...It is a font, like any other...So, go to fontawesome website, follow the instructions and download css + fonts.

Comment: I actually want to use offline CSS rather than online which links externally to improve page load time..

Comment: Using a CDN should actually improve page load time since that file is external, it should be downloaded in parallel with local assets.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. The version of FontAwesome I was using was outdated. I updated to use 4.7 and everything worked smoothly.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```